# Storing Characters above 128 in string array

Tags: vb.net

The VB.net code below works fine in earlier programs to use characters above 128
But it throws an error in current developments
It looks like the code page that holds the standard windows characters above 128 has disappeared behind the scenes. The code still works fine in older programs thankfully.

Any ideas ?

```
Public QAZ, conv As String
Public SREP(200) As String
Public I, J As Integer

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    
    For I = 128 To 190
        SREP(J) = Chr(I)

        J = J + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Tried adding the following line on advice. This stopped the error messages but the holding string array was blank.

```
Public SREP(200) As String

Public I, J As Integer

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    
    System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)
    
    J = 0
    For I = 128 To 190
        SREP(J) = Chr(I)

        J = J + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: VB.Net is using Unicode, not ASCII + Codepage. Additionally, there's no such thing as a "standard" windows code page. What you see in Windows by default depends on the language options. These are _per profile_, and even on the same windows installation different users might see different values for these characters.

Comment: Don't use VB conmpatibility functions like `Chr(I)`. Use .net `Convert.ToChar()` ot `char.FromUtf32`. These compatibility functions **CAN** behave differently.

Comment: Yea... and whats the error? Update your question

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to do?  This seems like a potential XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your issue is.  I tried this and it worked as expected.

```
    Dim SREP As New List(Of String)
    For I As Integer = 128 To 190
        Dim foo As Char = ChrW(I)
        SREP.Add(foo)
        Debug.WriteLine(foo)
    Next
```

I also tested this with the same results.

```
    Dim zSREP As New List(Of String)
    For I As Integer = 128 To 190
        Dim foo As Char = Convert.ToChar(I)
        zSREP.Add(foo)
        Debug.WriteLine(foo)
    Next
```

Results check.

```
Dim union As List(Of String) = SREP.Union(zSREP).ToList
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think this is the problem. It works sometimes but not others. I have applications where it works fine, then I on another project it fails with an error message or just returns blank. I need to find a way of making it work consistently. I don't understand why it should behave differently between developments. Hopefully someone can shed a light on the answer.

Comment: I made the following query on Google
what is the default Microsoft code page that has a standard 256 character set

answer
In Windows: Windows-1252
It uses a full byte (8-bits) to represent 256 different characters. Since Windows-1252 has been the default in Windows, it is supported by all browsers

IF I query what code page is in operation it says 1252 but something seems to come in between on different developments that affect the characters above 128. Given that I  am developing desktop apps rather than web apps, does this give a clue ?
Anyone know a simple fix to this issue.

Comment: The error message I get is : System.NotSupportedException: 'No data is available for encoding 1252. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.'

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to ensure that the chr() function works consistently and without causing errors for 128 to 256 character codes, using the original default windows character set, so that consistent characters are generated, seems to be to put this line early on in your program.

System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance)

I hope this saves others time in trying to wade through loads of complex and often witch doctor solutions to the problem.